# Why do I have to restart to get rid of refresh screen?

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

It seems that the refresh screen for the [Samsung Galaxy 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_3) isn't working correctly. If I or someone else edits a post, the "this question has been edited screen" pops up, but it will not go away and tell you to restart.

[image: Must restart to fix?]

Comment: The bar currently disappears if you tap it or leave the question.  It should probably disappear if you refresh by pulling down.  Is there any specific behavior you're looking for?

Comment: When i pull it down or tap it does not disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.0.84.

Tapping the bar or pulling to refresh will clear it.

Answer (score 0):

It should start remotely when you press the refresh button then it will stop the page from loading then restart.

Comment: Well this is for the app not the webpage and i understand what its supposed to do.

Answer (score -2):

Restart the phone, or server, wifi then reconnect the app..

Comment: Maybe you didn't read the accepted answer.